# Print Notifications

Tags: objective-c, nsnotificationcenter

How can I print every single notification on my system in obj-C?

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self ...];
```

what does in "..."? Should I use NSDistributedNotificationCenter?

let's say I have a function called logfunc which will do NSLog(@"ok");

thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(myMethod:) name:nil object:nil];
```

You can then define a method that matches your selector, like this:

```
- (void)myMethod:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSLog(@"notification received: %@", notification);
}
```

Comment: I had to use NSDistributedNotificationCenter to get all the notifications. Thanks!